# Bind different properties of a Class to two instances of the same UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls

I've created a simple `UserControl` that has a `TextBox` inside it and I've also created a Person class that has two properties 'FirstName' and 'LastName'.

I want to **reuse** that same `UserControl`, but bind different properties from the Person class to each instance of that `UserControls` TextProperty.

So I've created two instances of this same one `TextBox UserControl` in `Form1` by hosting them both in two seperate `ElementHost` controls.

Now I'm trying to bind the first `TextBox UserControls` TextProperty to my Person classes 'FirstName' property, and the other `TextBox UserControl` TextProperty to my Person classes 'LastName' property. Which I don't know how to do.

The end result should be two instances of my `TextBox UserControl`, one displaying the Person classes first name and the other instance displaying the Person classes last name. As I change the Person classes FirstName or LastName properties, the changes should be reflected to each `UserControl` through the binding.

I know I can add two of the `TextBoxs` into one single `UserControl` with `StackPanel` or something like that and set the binding up in the xaml, but that's not what I want. Is there a way to bind `UserControls` to other classes from outside their xaml or back code?

**UserControl code - TextBoxUC.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextBoxUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassPropertiesToTextBox"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbx" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Person.vb Class code**

```
Public Class Person
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private _firstname As String
  Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return _firstname
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _firstname = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName")
    End Set
  End Property

  Private _lastname As String
  Public Property LastName() As String
    Get
        Return _lastname
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _lastname = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName")
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
  Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
  End Sub
End Class
```

**Form1.vb Class code**

```
Public Class Form1

  'first TextBox UserControl to display Persons FirstName'
  Dim WithEvents tbxFirstNameUC As TextBoxUC
  'second TextBox UserControl to display Persons LastName'
  Dim WithEvents tbxLastNameUC As TextBoxUC
  'Person class to be used'
  Dim p As Person

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    p = New Person
    p.FirstName = "Homer"
    p.LastName = "Simpson"


    tbxFirstNameUC = New TextBoxUC
    'Set DataContext to my Person class instance'
    tbxFirstNameUC.DataContext = p
    'Set binding of Person classes FirstName to my first instance TextBox UserControls Text Property'
    'Cant get TextBoxes TextProperty'
    tbxFirstNameUC.tbx.SetBinding(tbxFirstNameUC.tbx.Text, New Binding("FirstName", p, p.FirstName))
    'host FirstName TextBox UserControl as a child of ElementHost control'
    hostTbxFN.Child = tbxFirstNameUC


    tbxLastNameUC = New TextBoxUC
    'Set DataContext to my Person class instance'
    tbxLastNameUC.DataContext = p
    'Set binding of Person classes FirstName to my first instance TextBox UserControls Text Property'
    'Cant get TextBoxes TextProperty'
    tbxLastNameUC.tbx.SetBinding(tbxLastNameUC.tbx.Text, New Binding("LastName", p, p.LastName))
    'host LastName TextBox UserControl as a child of ElementHost control'
    hostTbxLN.Child = tbxLastNameUC
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a string dependency property to the `UserControl` class (TextBoxUC.xaml.vb):

```
Public Class TextBoxUC

    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return CType(Me.GetValue(TextProperty), Boolean)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.SetValue(TextProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly TextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", GetType(String), GetType(TextBoxUC), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))
End Class
```

And bind the `TextBox` in the `UserControl` (TextBoxUC.xaml) to this one:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbx" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Then you could just bind this dependency property to a property of the `Person` `DataContext` as usual:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassPropertiesToTextBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Person FirstName="Mickey" LastName="Mouse" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:TextBoxUC Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Edit:** Or you could bind the dependency property programmatically:

```
p = New Person
p.FirstName = "Homer"
p.LastName = "Simpson"

tbxFirstNameUC = New TextBoxUC
'Set DataContext to my Person class instance'
tbxFirstNameUC.DataContext = p
tbxFirstNameUC.SetBinding(TextBoxUC.NameProperty, New Binding("FirstName"))
```

Comment: You're binding the Person classes 'FirstName' to the `TextBox UserControl` in a WPF Application Window, but I need to create this binding in a Windows Form like in my example or I wouldn't mind passing the Person class in `Form1.vb` as a reference to the 'TextBoxUC' `UserControl` in `Form1`, maybe through the constructor or method and creating the binding in the code behind of that `UserControl`, but I don't know the code to set that up. I'm using a Windows Form Application, not a WPF Application but I'm integrating `UserControls` through `ElementHost` Controls.

Comment: I also tried dependency properties, but I don't know how to connect it through code, only through xaml. Thanks anyway

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to bind to the dependency property programmatically. Hope that helps.

Comment: Was having problems getting your updated solution working, figured out that .SetBinding(TextBoxUC.NameProperty,...) needed to be changed to TextBoxUC.TextProperty for it to display in the TextBox. Thanks